# How to replace several characters in a string using Julia

Tags: string, replace, julia

I'm essentially trying to solve this problem: http://rosalind.info/problems/revc/

I want to replace all occurrences of A, C, G, T with their compliments T, G, C, A .. in other words all A's will be replaced with T's, all C's with G's and etc.

I had previously used the `replace()` function to replace all occurrences of 'T' with 'U' and was hoping that the replace function would take a list of characters to replace with another list of characters but I haven't been able to make it work, so it might not have that functionality.

I know I could solve this easily using the BioJulia package and have done so using the following:

```
# creating complementary strand of DNA
# reverse the string
# find the complementary nucleotide
using Bio.Seq
s = dna"AAAACCCGGT"

t = reverse(complement(s))

println("$t")
```

But I'd like to not have to rely on the package.

Here's the code I have so far, if someone could steer me in the right direction that'd be great.

```
# creating complementary strand of DNA
# reverse the string
# find the complementary nucleotide

s = open("nt.txt") # open file containing sequence

t = reverse(s) # reverse the sequence

final = replace(t, r'[ACGT]', '[TGCA]') # this is probably incorrect
# replace characters ACGT with TGCA

println("$final")
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems that `replace` doesn't yet do translations quite like, say, `tr` in Bash. So instead, here are couple of approaches using a dictionary mapping instead (the BioJulia package also appears to make similar use of dictionaries):

```
compliments = Dict('A' => 'T', 'C' => 'G', 'G' => 'C', 'T' => 'A')
```

Then if `str = "AAAACCCGGT"`, you could use `join` like this:

```
julia> join([compliments[c] for c in str])
"TTTTGGGCCA"
```

Another approach could be to use a function and `map`:

```
function translate(c)
    compliments[c]
end
```

Then:

```
julia> map(translate, str)
"TTTTGGGCCA"
```

Strings are iterable objects in Julia; each of these approaches reads one character in turn, `c`, and passes it to the dictionary to get back the complimentary character. A *new* string is built up from these complimentary characters.

Julia's strings are also immutable: you can't swap characters around in place, rather you need to build a new string.

Comment: This works perfectly when I supply str = "AAACCCGGT", but if I try to open a file and obtain the string that way, I get a 'not found in getindex at dict' error.

Also, could you elaborate a bit on how the function at the bottom solves my problem? How does indexing the dictionary alter my string? I'm currently reading Mastering Julia, but am only a few chapters in and just picked up Julia yesterday so while I understand a bit, i'm still quite unfamiliar with a few of the mechanics, this being one.

Comment: Regaridng the error, it's possible you're reading in the newline(s) from the file. These aren't mapped by the dictionary so the error arises. You could try `map(translate, readchomp(s))`.

Comment: `map(translate, str)` will return a new translated string based on str, similarly `replace(str, match, replacement)` will return a new string too, ie: `x = "test"; y = replace(x, 'e', 'E'); x, y` returns `("test","tEst")`. They will **not** update your original string in place!

Comment: @IsmaelVenegasCastelló: am I right in thinking there's no (convenient) way to modify Julia's strings in place since they're immutable? I'm still learning about Julia myself and curious to know if I've missed anything.

Comment: @ajcr I don't think so, you might want to take a look at [`MutableStrings.jl`](https://github.com/tanmaykm/MutableStrings.jl) and [`Strings.jl`](https://github.com/quinnj/Strings.jl) for an idiomatic way to do that! :D